# Why does including width make margin: auto center block level elements correctly?

Tags: html, css

If I have a block level element and I select it in CSS and declare the CSS rule   `margin: auto;` then nothing happends. But when I include   `width: 100px;` it suddenly becomes centered in the middle of the screen. Why does including `width` make this occur?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but margin: auto; relies on a defined width for both the parent and child element?

Comment: @DavidCalvin `margin: auto;` only needs a block level element. Percentage heights on a child element however do require the parent to have a set height also.

Comment: Becaue initially the div occupies full width but whwn you mention width in css as like width:100px and margin: auto. The width will be set and aligned centered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually does center the div! If you try to put a color to the div you will see that the div actually fills the whole width of the page and is actually centered (or better to say that they have filled the whole that they have no place to move horizontally).

divs fill the width of their parent automatically if you don't define a width to them.

If you put `width: 100px' to them that just makes it obvious that it was actually centered.

**UPDATE (hungerstar wants it to be more technical):**

You have a parent container with a 500px width and a child in it that you have styled `margin 0 auto;`

That child is centered but it's just not obvious. Why? because that div automatically fits itself inside its parent (divs have `width: auto;` as default if you don't specify it) therefore its width is also 500px with space left for it to move horizontally in its parent.

If you specify a width larger than 500px then it will spill to the right of its parent container because browsers prioritize the left margin first but if you specify it with 400px as width then `margin: 0 auto;` will kick in and calculate the left margin first by `(parent_width - this_child_width)/2` and then assign the right margin by whatever space left based on that equation.

Therefore we have `this_child_width = 500px` and `parent_width = 500px` therefore `(500px-500px)/2 = 0`. 0 margin on the left and right = CENTERED.

Comment: This is an answer to his question. The question is: _Why does including width make margin: auto center block level elements correctly?_ therefore this is a valid answer.

Comment: Validating that something works is not an answer. Saying it fills the whole with doesn't explain **how**  setting the margins of a block level element to `auto` centers it. Well, in a very vague roundabout way it does, because it will take up the whole width. I would like to see something more technical. Something that says, how do I determine that this element will be centered and take up the whole width?

Comment: @hungerstar you clearly can't see the point sir. That's the actual answer, it's already centered if you put `margin: 0 auto` on it but you just can't see it because it won't actually show up if it fills the entire width. If you put a smaller width to it than it was before then the centering will occur obviously.

Comment: I can see how you could make the argument that something that takes up 100% width could be considered centered. Beyond that you're stating observations. Not explaining how the browser determines where to place the element when a set width is provided. Please answer this, _"How does the browser know how much left and right margin to add?"_

Comment: @hungerstar *if you have a box that fits exactly and automatically inside the box wouldn't you consider that box as centered?*

Comment: @hungerstar divs have `width: auto;` by default and that automatically streches the div to the entire length available that are not occupied by margins or paddings. If you put `margin: 0 auto;` on it of course the browser would calculate 0 margins left and right. NOW specifying the width now defies the default auto width and the browser now calculates the space less the width of the block element then distributes it both to left and right. I shouldn't explain it as far as this. You just don't want to accept this as an answer. I just answered it as simple as I can to avoid confusion.

Comment: You could, but you could consider it aligned to the [right](http://jsfiddle.net/hfej7ndc/) or [left](http://jsfiddle.net/hfej7ndc/) also if it's taking up the full width. That's why I said, _"I can see how...could be considered centered."_.

Comment: Now that answer is more what I was looking for. :) I think the extra details are justified based on how the OP asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually. Auto-calculating the margins needs a reference point.

The equation would look like this:

`container - width = total margin allowance`

Given a 1000px container and 700px element inside the container:

`1000px - 700px = 300px for margins`

If you only had one auto margin, then that margin would be `300px`. If you had two margins, like `margin: 0 auto;`, which sets the left and right margins, you would get `150px` for each the left and right margin, `300px / 2 = 150px`. Adding the same amount of margin on each side of a set width block level element is what creates the centering effect.

Now try the equation without a set width.

`1000px - ?? = ?? for margins`

Single margin is `?? / 1 = 100% of ??` and two margins are `?? / 2 =  50% of ??`.

Percentage width work fine also because:

`1000px - 50% = 500px` or `1000px - 500px = 500px` (as 50% of 1000px is 500px)